# Using live streaming with Red5 from embedded device

Tags: embedded, red5

I am using MSp430F5418 controller for an embedded device. I want to live broadcast some content to a red5 server from the device (Red5 server is in another computer, not in the embedded device). I have attached a camera and a microphone to my device. Can anybody share some thoughts for doing that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Red5 is written in Java.  I am not aware of a Java implementation that runs on the MSP430 family of processors
2. The MSP430 running at its top speed of 25MHz just does not have the processing power to handle video and audio processing.
3. The total RAM available on this processor is only 16kByte.  Not really enough for this type of application.
4. ....

Comment: I don't want to run the red5 server on msp430. I want a client application written in C, to send some video content to the server running red5 server. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Points 2 and 3 still apply.  I would be interested about the interface that you intend to use to pass the video data, both into the MSP and then out to the server.

Comment: To MSP I am planning to use RS232. To Server it is GSM modem connected via RS232. If there any speed limitation I can also use SPI.

Comment: And the data rate is...?  Image data size, frame rate, audio data rate...?

Comment: Hmm... Let's say the maximum possible data rates. I haven't implemented it, I wanted to check whether it is possible/feasible to implement it.